# Using multiprocessing on Image processing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to speed up my processing of a `PIL.Image`, where I divide the image into small parts, search for the most similar image inside a database and then replace the original small part of the image with this found image.
This is the described function:

```
def work_image(img, lenx, leny, neigh, split_dict, img_train_rot):
    constructed_img = Image.new(mode='L', size=img.size)
    for x in range(0,img.size[0],lenx):
        for y in range(0,img.size[1],leny):  
            box = (x,y,x+lenx,y+leny)
            split_img = img.crop(box)
            res = neigh.kneighbors(np.asarray(split_img).ravel().reshape((1,-1)))
            #look up the found image part in img_train_rot and define the position as new_box
            constructed_img.paste(img_train_rot[i].crop(new_box), (x,y))
    return constructed_img
```

Now I wanted to parallelize this function, since f.e. each row of such image parts could be dealt with entirely on its own.
I came up with this approach using `multiprocessing.Pool`:

```
def work_image_parallel(leny, neigh, split_dict, img_train_rot, img_slice):
    constructed_img_slice = Image.new(mode='L', size=img_slice.size)
    for y in range(0, img_slice.size[1], leny):
        box = (0, y, img_slice.size[0], y+leny)
        img_part = img_slice.crop(box)
        res = neigh.kneighbors(np.asarray(img_part).ravel().reshape((1,-1)))
        #look up the found image part in img_train_rot and define the position as new_box
        constructed_img_slice.paste(img_train_rot[i].crop(new_box), (0,y))
    return constructed_img_slice

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lenx, leny = 16, 16
    #define my image database and so on
    neigh = setup_nearest_neighbour(train_imgs, n_neighbors=1)
    test_img = test_imgs[0]
    func = partial(work_image_parallel, leny, neigh, split_dict, img_train_rot)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    try:
        res = pool.map(func, map(lambda x: x, [test_img.crop((x, 0, x+lenx, test_img.size[1])) for x in range(0, test_img.size[0], lenx)])) 
    finally:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    test_result2 = Image.new(mode='L', size = test_img.size)
    for i in range(len(res)):
        test_result2.paste(res[i], box=(i*lenx, 0, i*lenx + lenx, test_result2.size[1]))
```

However, this parallelized version isn't exactly faster than the normal version, and if I decrease the size of my image division, the parallelized version throws an AssertionError (other posts said this might be because the data size to be sent between the processes becomes too big).

Therefore my question, did I maybe do something wrong? Is multiprocessing maybe not the right approach here? Or why doesn't the multiprocessing decrease the computation time, since the workload per image slice should be big enough to offset the time needed to create processes etc.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I am not that familiar with PIL so you may should take a close look at the PIL method calls, which may need some "adjustment" on your part since there is no way that I can actually test this.

First, I observe that you will probably be making a lot of repeated invocations of your worker function `work_image_parallel` and that some of those arguments being passed to that function might be quite large (all of this depends, of course, on how large your images are). Rather than repeatedly passing such potentially large arguments, I would prefer to copy these arguments once to each process in your pool and instantiate them as global variables. This is accomplished with a pool initializer function.

Second, I have attempted to modify your `work_image_parallel` function to be as close to your original `work_image` function except that it now deals with just a single x, y coordinate pair that is passed to it. In that way more of the work is being done by your subprocesses. I have also tried to reduce the number of pasting operations required (if I have correctly understood what is going on).

Third, because the images may be quite large, I am using a generator expression to create the arguments to be used with `imap_unordered` instead of `map`. This is because the number of x, y pairs can be quite large in a very large image and `map` requires that its *iterable* argument be such that its length can be computed so that an efficient *chunksize* value can be computed (see the docs). With `imap_unordered`, we should specify an explicit *chunksize* value to be efficient (the default is 1 if unspecified) if we expect that the *iterable* could be large. If you know that you are dealing with relatively small images so that the size of the `x_y_args` *iterable* would not be unreasonably memory-inefficient if stored as a list, then, you could just use method `map` with the default `chunksize` value of `None` and have the pool compute the value for you. The advantage of using `imap_unordered` is that results do not have to be returned in order, so processing could be faster.

```py
def init_pool(the_img, the_img_train_rot, the_neigh, the_split_dict):
    global img, img_train_rot, neigh, split_dict
    img = the_img
    img_train_rot = the_img_train_rot
    neigh = the_neigh
    split_dict = the_split_dict

def work_image_parallel(lenx, leny, t):
    x, y = t
    box = (x,y,x+lenx,y+leny)
    split_img = img.crop(box)
    res = neigh.kneighbors(np.asarray(split_img).ravel().reshape((1,-1)))
    #look up the found image part in img_train_rot and define the position as new_box
    # return original x, y values used:
    return x, y, img_train_rot[i].crop(new_box)

def compute_chunksize(iterable_size, pool_size):
    chunksize, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, 4 * pool_size)
    if remainder:
        chunksize += 1
    return chunksize

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lenx, leny = 16, 16
    #define my image database and so on
    neigh = setup_nearest_neighbour(train_imgs, n_neighbors=1)
    test_img = test_imgs[0]
    func = partial(work_image_parallel, lenx, leny)
    # in case this is a very large image, use a generator expression
    x_y_args = ((x, y) for x in range(0, test_img.size[0], lenx) for y in range(0, test_img.size[1], leny))
    # approximate size of x_y_args:
    iterable_size = (test_img.size[0] // lenx) * (test_img.size[1] // leny)
    pool_size = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    chunksize = compute_chunksize(iterable_size, pool_size)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(pool_size, initiializer=init_pool, initargs=(test_img, img_train_rot, neigh, split_dict))
    test_result2 = Image.new(mode='L', size = test_img.size)
    try:
        # use imap or imap_unordered when the iterable is a generator to avoid conversion of iterable to a list
        # but specify a suitable chunksize for efficiency in case the iterable is very large:
        for x, y, res in pool.imap_unordered(func, x_y_args, chunksize=chunksize):
            test_result2.paste(res, (x, y))
    finally:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

**Update (break up image into bigger slices)**

```py
def init_pool(the_img, the_img_train_rot, the_neigh, the_split_dict):
    global img, img_train_rot, neigh, split_dict
    img = the_img
    img_train_rot = the_img_train_rot
    neigh = the_neigh
    split_dict = the_split_dict

def work_image_parallel(lenx, leny, x):
    img_slice = img.crop((x, 0, x+lenx, img.size[1]))
    constructed_img_slice = Image.new(mode='L', size=img_slice.size)
    for y in range(0, img_slice.size[1], leny):
        box = (0, y, img_slice.size[0], y+leny)
        img_part = img_slice.crop(box)
        res = neigh.kneighbors(np.asarray(img_part).ravel().reshape((1,-1)))
        #look up the found image part in img_train_rot and define the position as new_box
        constructed_img_slice.paste(img_train_rot[i].crop(new_box), (0,y))
    return constructed_img_slice

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lenx, leny = 16, 16
    #define my image database and so on
    neigh = setup_nearest_neighbour(train_imgs, n_neighbors=1)
    test_img = test_imgs[0]
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(pool_size, initiializer=init_pool, initargs=(test_img, img_train_rot, neigh, split_dict))
    func = partial(work_image_parallel, lenx, leny)
    try:
        test_result2 = Image.new(mode='L', size = test_img.size)
        x = 0
        for res in pool.map(func, [x for x in range(0, test_img.size[0], lenx)]):
            test_result2.paste(res, box=(x, 0, x + lenx, test_result2.size[1]))
            x += lenx
    finally:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your suggestions make very much sense, however, after implementing them, the running time of my code skyrocketed. Since the workload basically stayed the same, I guess some kind of process communication pattern doesn't work optimally. Do you have any ideas what could have gone wrong?

Comment: I really don't know enough about what is being done by `work_image_parallel` to answer your question. Perhaps now the running time of that function is so small that the added overhead of multiprocessing (time it takes moving data from one address space to another) is what is blowing the time up. I have added an update to the answer with a new version of the code where `work_image_parallel` is more like your original version of that function. Make sure it makes sense.

Comment: The comment I added in `work_image_parallel` basically replaces a lookup in the `split_dict` dictionary from which image the found most similar image part originates, as given by `neigh`, and the exact position of this image part in said image, so nothing really expanssive. Your update brought the running time down to ~80% of the non-parallelized version, but I would suspect this gain to increase as the images get bigger (right now images are ~350x350 split into 16x16 sized parts).

Comment: So if you are satisfied you can *accept* the answer.

Comment: I'm left with 2 questionss though, why do you divide in your `compute_chunksize` function by `4*pool_size` instead of only `pool_size`? Also, my PC apparently can't handle the pool taking the maximum number of processes (6), it only lags and stutters around and the computation doesn't finish, so right now I'm only using `pool_size=4`. Is this a common occurence?

Comment: First, the updated version using `map` no longer uses `compute_chunksize`. That said, when you do use `map` with the default *chunksize* argument of `None`, the pool instance will compute a `chunksize`  value to be used using  a function that is essentially equivalent to the one I provided.  If you have N processes, you do not want to divide all  the submitted tasks into N roughly equal chunks (one per process). If one of those tasks is very long running, N - 1 processors will finish their chunks and remain idle while the other processor is working on its chunk. Better to have 4 * N chunks.

Comment: (Tasks are placed on a queue in chunks of size *chunksize* and an idle processor will take off the queue the next chunk and process all of the tasks in that chunk before becoming idle again). I don't have a good explanation for your second question; it is *not* a common experience.

Comment: Ok I see. Thank you for your help.